# Excel Listbox displays default value but does not retain in within Sub

Tags: listbox

I have an issue that is stumping me. I have a large VBA app and I have isolated the offending piece of code here. Basically I have a UserForm with a few ListBoxes (I used 8 ListBoxes here to make the point). Based on some prior user input, each of the listboxes will present some default value. I found some curious behaviour I can duplicate here but can't explain. Only some of the listBoxes seem retain the default value that I set (even though the userform displays the set values)
Here is the sequence of steps to try to prove my issue:

Open UserForm4
Run
In Input Box Asking "Pre-Enter some Default Values?", Enter "Y"
  You will see that I set the ListBox.Value for each ListBox to a certain value as displayed by the highlighted items in the ListBoxes. If I choose not to chance the default values (by not clicking any item in the listbox),some of the ListBox.Value(s) do not "stick".
This is made obvious when you Click on the Command button (Show ListBoxValues) that displays the ListBox,Values, you will see all the ListBox.Values do not seem to have got their values set as seen from the MsgBox Output. Specifically ListBox3.Value, ListBox6.Value and ListBox8.Value seem to be "" or NULL even though they were set to specific values exactly like the other ListBox.Values were.

Any Ideas why?

I have the code in the .frm file and the .frx file so you can duplicate it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nu9kSSpWCHk5m2-QIthJjNxS_DDEa1kt/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-LWNe8IiLe1JJRC-of5bSX3Oer8eP7Y/view?usp=sharing

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
myValue = inputbox("Pre-Enter some Default Values?(Y/N)")

With ListBox1
   .AddItem "Listbox1-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox1-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox1-C"
End With

With ListBox2
   .AddItem "Listbox2-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox2-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox2-C"
End With

With ListBox3
   .AddItem "Listbox3-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox3-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox3-C"
End With

With ListBox4
   .AddItem "Listbox4-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox4-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox4-C"
End With

With ListBox5
   .AddItem "Listbox5-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox5-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox5-C"
End With

With ListBox6
   .AddItem "Listbox6-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox6-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox6-C"
End With

With ListBox7
   .AddItem "Listbox7-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox7-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox7-C"
End With
With ListBox8
   .AddItem "Listbox8-A"
   .AddItem "Listbox8-B"
   .AddItem "Listbox8-C"
End With

If UCase(myValue) = "Y" Then
ListBox1.Value = "Listbox1-B"
ListBox2.Value = "Listbox2-B"
ListBox3.Value = "Listbox3-B"
ListBox4.Value = "Listbox4-B"
ListBox5.Value = "Listbox5-B"
ListBox6.Value = "Listbox6-B"
ListBox7.Value = "Listbox7-B"
ListBox8.Value = "Listbox8-B"
End If
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox UserForm4.ListBox1.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox2.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox3.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox4.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox5.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox6.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox7.Value & vbCrLf & _
UserForm4.ListBox8.Value & vbCrLf

End
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code here on SO, in case that link ever stops working.

Comment: allenski: Thanks for commenting. I posted the code. Let me know if you can duplicate it. Thanks again!